# How to specify the base docker image I want to use in the application.properties, using Quarkus

Tags: java, docker, quarkus, docker-image, application.properties

I'm trying Quarkus and was just wondering if there is a possibility to specify the docker image in the application.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in our projects to generate the Dockerfiles during the build at some point and, if we do that, configuring the base image will be possible.

But for now, you need to tweak the Dockerfiles we create when generating the project.

Comment: Thank you very much.